Interactive plot stuck interacting with first element (Python, tkinter)
I am building a program which reduces mass spectrometer data: it should present the user with the raw data from an analysis and allow them to interactively click a datum to remove it as an outlier. Once a datum is removed, the data, trendline, and statistics should be automatically recalculated. The program also provides buttons below the data to go to the next or previous analysis to inspect it for outliers.
This works perfectly for the first analysis out of every sequence, but when I try to remove a datum from any other analysis (e.g. after clicking "Next"), the plot reverts to the first analysis and removes the datum from that data set rather than from the one I was working on. It seems that I'm stuck interacting with the first plot element in the array, rather than the one I'm viewing (unless I'm viewing the first).
Here's the interactivity logic:

main.py calls the function setup_interacive_plot() then sets up the main window loop.

from import_raw import get_raw_data
from select_sequences import filter_data
from interactive_plot import setup_interactive_plot, interactive_update
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
import tkinter as tk


# next button
def on_next(current_plot_index):
    current_plot_index = (current_plot_index + 1) % len(filtered_data)
    interactive_update(filtered_data[current_plot_index], figure, canvas, stats_frame)
    update_buttons()


# previous button
def on_previous(current_plot_index):
    current_plot_index = (current_plot_index - 1) % len(filtered_data)
    interactive_update(filtered_data[current_plot_index], figure, canvas, stats_frame)
    update_buttons()


# finish button (to do)
def on_finish():
    window.quit() # replace with call to data reduction script


# exit button
def on_exit():
    window.quit()


# remove previous button on first index
# replace next with finish on last index
def update_buttons():
    prev_button.pack_forget()
    next_button.pack_forget()
    finish_button.pack_forget()

    if current_plot_index > 0:
        prev_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    
    if current_plot_index == len(filtered_data) - 1:
        finish_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    else:  
        next_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)



### main code below ###


matplotlib.use('TkAgg') # forces TkAgg backend to matplotlib (for MacOSX development)

# get and filter raw data
global filtered_data
all_data, sequence_data = get_raw_data() # get all raw data and group into sequences
filtered_data           = filter_data(all_data, sequence_data) # filter out only the selected sequences

# initiate GUI
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('HeMan - Alphachron Data Reduction')

# define and pack main frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(window)
main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# define and pack frame for statistics panel on the left
stats_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, borderwidth=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
stats_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

# define and pack frame for data plot and buttons on the right
right_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
right_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X, expand=True)

# define and pack frame for buttons
button_frame = tk.Frame(right_frame)
button_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X) 

# define and pack frame for data 
data_frame = tk.Frame(right_frame)
data_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# initialize and pack the data frame
global canvas
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=data_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# set current_plot_index
current_plot_index = 0

# initialize and pack buttons
global prev_button, exit_button, next_button, finish_button
button_options = {'width': 10, 'height': 2}
exit_button    = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Exit", command=lambda: on_exit(), **button_options)
prev_button    = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Previous", command=lambda: on_previous(current_plot_index), **button_options)
next_button    = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Next", command=lambda: on_next(current_plot_index), **button_options)
finish_button  = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Finish", command=lambda: on_finish(), **button_options)
prev_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
exit_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
next_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
finish_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

# update the panes
update_buttons()
setup_interactive_plot(filtered_data[current_plot_index], figure, canvas, stats_frame)

# main window loop
window.mainloop()


setup_interactive_plot() in interactive_plot.py runs plot_raw_data() to generate the figure, format it, place it on the tk canvas, and write the associated stats pane. It then sets up on_click interactivity with the fig.canvas.mpl_connect() command.

def setup_interactive_plot(data_entry, fig, canvas, stats_frame):
    plot_raw_data(data_entry, fig, canvas) # draw raw data to data frame
    write_stats_frame(data_entry, stats_frame) # write stats to stats frame

    # interactivity
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: on_click(event, data_entry, fig, canvas, stats_frame))


# draw the raw data plots on the data frame
def plot_raw_data(data_entry, fig, canvas):
    update_plot_and_trendlines(data_entry, fig) # generate the figure
    plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust spacing to prevent labels overlapping
    plt.suptitle(f"He {data_entry.helium_number}: {data_entry.analysis_label}")
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.92)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    canvas.draw()



on_click() checks whether the click landed within a plot window; if so, it finds the closest datum to the click, and 'inactivates' it by setting the corresponding entry data_entry.data_status[mass] from 1 to 0 or vice versa.

# what to do when the user clicks on the plot
def on_click(event, data_entry, figure, canvas, stats_frame):
    click_coords = (event.xdata, event.ydata) # click coordinates

    # check whether the click landed inside a plot and if so, get the plot and closest_index
    try:
        mass          = event.inaxes.get_title() # get axis title of click plot
        closest_index = find_closest_index(data_entry.raw_data, click_coords, mass) # closest index to click
    except AttributeError:
        return # click outside of bounds, do nothing

    # toggle the clicked datum between 1 (active) and 0 (inactive)
    data_entry.data_status[mass].iloc[closest_index] = (data_entry.data_status[mass].iloc[closest_index] + 1) % 2
    if mass in ['3 amu', '4 amu']: # if any datum is excluded from 3 amu or 4 amu, also exclude it from the 4/3 Ratio
            data_entry.data_status['4/3 Ratio'].iloc[closest_index] = (data_entry.data_status['4/3 Ratio'].iloc[closest_index] + 1) % 2

    interactive_update(data_entry, figure, canvas, stats_frame)


on_click() ends by calling interactive_update(), which clears the figure, draws a new one with plot_raw_data(), and updates the stats frame with the new statistics.

# run all interactive update features in one function
def interactive_update(data_entry, fig, canvas, stats_frame):
    fig.clf()
    plot_raw_data(data_entry, fig, canvas) # draw raw data on data frame canvas
    write_stats_frame(data_entry, stats_frame) # write stats to stats frame


interactive_update() is also called when I click the next or previous buttons defined in main.py:

# next button
def on_next(current_plot_index):
    current_plot_index = (current_plot_index + 1) % len(filtered_data)
    interactive_update(filtered_data[current_plot_index], figure, canvas, stats_frame)
    update_buttons()


# previous button
def on_previous(current_plot_index):
    current_plot_index = (current_plot_index - 1) % len(filtered_data)
    interactive_update(filtered_data[current_plot_index], figure, canvas, stats_frame)
    update_buttons()

I suspect I'm doing something stupid like incorrectly using a global or something, but I'm pretty stumped.
Here are the complete scripts as they stand as of writing this (I've removed some irrelevant features and statements from the above for readability):

main.py
import_raw.py
interactive_plot.py
plot_data.py

There are also scripts write_stats.py, he_stats.py, and select_sequences.py. I believe these are irrelevant but they can be provided, along with raw data, if someone is interested in running the script and trying it out themselves.

I was creating a single click handler for the first plot and wasn't removing it or generating a new one for each new plot. Here's the corrected code:
current_click_handler = None

# attach the click handler to the new figure
def attach_click_handler(analysis, figure, canvas, stats_frame):
    global current_click_handler

    # disconnect the old handler if it exists
    if current_click_handler is not None:
        figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(current_click_handler)

    click_handler = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: on_click(event, analysis, figure, canvas, stats_frame))
    current_click_handler = click_handler

# run all interactive update features in one function
def interactive_update(analysis, figure, canvas, stats_frame):
    figure.clf()
    plot_raw_data(analysis, figure, canvas) # draw raw data on data frame canvas
    write_stats_frame(analysis, stats_frame) # write stats to stats frame

    attach_click_handler(analysis, figure, canvas, stats_frame)


def setup_interactive_plot(analysis, figure, canvas, stats_frame):
    plot_raw_data(analysis, figure, canvas) # draw raw data to data frame
    write_stats_frame(analysis, stats_frame) # write stats to stats frame

    attach_click_handler(analysis, figure, canvas, stats_frame)

